# Converting Hibernate query to Sub query for 3 conditions

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, subquery

This method is working perfectly as my requirement.But I want to query with DB only once.

I have 2 conditions to check with DB for querying and displaying List data in UI.Each time I am accessing DB and checking list size and performing action.

For one data list with same table I am querying 3 times.Which is not efficient way I think. And wrote sub queries for it.But could not succeed with it.

**So any efficient way for writing this and optimizing my method..?**

**query1**: `"FROM Produce where produceId not in (:produceIdList) and itemName in (:itemNameList)" + " and farmerUuid not in(" + merchantUuid + ") and lastDateForBid>=CURDATE() order by lastDateForBid Asc";`

> Condition: If(result>=10) return data
>              else check  for query2

**query2**: `"FROM Produce where produceId not in (:produceIdList) and farmerUuid not in(" + merchantUuid + ")" + "and itemName in (:itemNameList) and categoryId in (:categoryList) and lastDateForBid>=CURDATE() order by lastDateForBid Asc";`

> Condition: If(result>=10) return data
>              else check  for **query3**

**query3**:

`"FROM Produce where produceId not in (:produceIdList) and farmerUuid not in(" + merchantUuid + ") and lastDateForBid>=CURDATE() order by lastDateForBid Asc ";`

**This is my method**

```
    mId = merchantUuid;
    Long produceId = null;
    String itemName = null;
    Long categoryId = null;
    List<Long> categoryList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    List<Long> produceIdList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    List<Produce> produceList = new ArrayList<Produce>();
    List<String> itemNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Bidding> biddingList = getBiddingForMerchant();
    int count = biddingList.size();
    if (count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            produceId = biddingList.get(i).getProduce().getProduceId();
            if(!produceIdList.contains(produceId)){
            produceIdList.add(produceId);
            }
            itemName = biddingList.get(i).getProduce().getItemName();
            if (!itemNameList.contains(itemName)) {
                itemNameList.add(itemName);
            }
            categoryId = biddingList.get(i).getProduce().getCategory().getCategoryId();
            if (!categoryList.contains(categoryId)) {
                categoryList.add(categoryId);
            }
        }
        String ProduceQuery1 = "FROM Produce where produceId not in (:produceIdList)"
                + " and itemName in (:itemNameList)" + " and farmerUuid not in(" + merchantUuid + ")"
                + " and lastDateForBid>=CURDATE() order by lastDateForBid Asc";
        Query q1 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(ProduceQuery1);
        q1.setParameterList("itemNameList", itemNameList);
        q1.setParameterList("produceIdList", produceIdList);
        //q1.setMaxResults(10);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Produce> produceList1 = q1.list();
        produceList.addAll(produceList1);
        if (produceList.size() ==10) {
            return produceList;
        }

        else if (produceList.size() < 10) {
            String produceQuery2 = "FROM Produce where produceId not in (:produceIdList)"
                    + " and farmerUuid not in(" + merchantUuid + ")" + "and itemName in (:itemNameList)"
                    + " and categoryId in (:categoryList) "
                    + " and lastDateForBid>=CURDATE() order by lastDateForBid Asc";
            Query q2 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(produceQuery2);
            System.out.println("produceQuery::" + produceQuery2);
            q2.setParameterList("produceIdList", produceIdList);
            q2.setParameterList("itemNameList", itemNameList);
            q2.setParameterList("categoryList", categoryList);
            //q2.setMaxResults(10);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Produce> produceList2 = q2.list();
            produceList.clear();
            produceList.addAll(produceList2);

            if (produceList.size() > 9) {
               List<Produce> produceListNew = produceList.subList(0,10);
               return produceListNew;
            }

            else {
                String produceQuery3 = "FROM Produce where produceId not in (:produceIdList)"
                        + " and farmerUuid not in(" + merchantUuid + ")"
                        + " and lastDateForBid>=CURDATE() order by lastDateForBid Asc ";
                Query q3 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(produceQuery3);
                q3.setParameterList("produceIdList", produceIdList);
                //q3.setMaxResults(10);
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Produce> produceList3 = q3.list();
                produceList.clear();
                produceList.addAll(produceList3);

                if(produceList.size()>10){
                produceList = produceList.subList(0,10);
                }
                return produceList;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you..!!